# protobuf-csharp-port what version(s) of these tools are best to use today?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, protocol-buffers

On a Mac, using Mono 2.6, and wanting to get started with protobuf-csharp-port.

I just compiled protoc from protobuf-2.3.0 from google. Or should I use protobuf-2.4.0 which recently came out?  Also for protobuf-csharp-port should I use the Download of 0.9.1 (May 2010) or go ahead and clone the Git master branch?

So, looks like successfully compiled the AddressBook tutorial using 2.3.0 +  0.9.1. Wanting to know if it's advisable to go with protoc 2.4.0 + git master?

Thanks in advance and looking forward to digging in to protobuf-csharp-port.
Alex

Comment: (changed tags; if you are using protobuf-csharp-port you aren't using protobuf-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I've used protobuf-csharp-port on a Mac. It's *probably* best to go with the 2.3.0 build of protobuf as that's the version of protoc I use on Windows.

I would suggest using the latest version of protobuf-csharp-port on github; that includes a few new features in ProtoGen such as automatically calling protoc for you - although it assumes protoc.exe, so you'll need to tinker with it to call the Mac version. You can also specify various of the generation options from the command line instead of "polluting" an otherwise portable .proto file, which is nice. Unfortunately I don't have documentation for that yet, but feel free to ask for information on any specific bit :)

The github repository also has support for the "lite" runtime, if that's useful to you. That's a reasonably recent addition which hasn't had as much usage as the rest yet, just to warn you. I don't know of any problems, but just be aware of its recentness :)

Comment: I found this answer in attempts to use ProtocolBuffersLite in a PCL. Apparently, I need to use the 'lite' switch. Still looking for it.

Comment: @bohdan_trotsenko: You use the option of `optimize_for="LITE_RUNTIME"` - see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options.